# Selenium wait until element is clickable, using relative element in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriverwait

There is a way to use the element_to_be_clickable method by passing as a parameter a webelement and not a locator (By) as can be done in Java.

The problem is because the element I want to wait for until it is clickable is obtained by looking for it in a relative way by xpath in another webelement.

```html
<ul class="my-list">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea
        <div class="acction">
            click-me
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>bread
        <div class="acction">
            click-me
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My Java code

```java
var items = driver.findElementsByXPath("//ul[@class='my-list']//li");
items.forEach(item -> {
    try {
        var action = item.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='acction']"));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(action)).click();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ignored) {
    }
});
```

Is there a way I can do the same using selenium in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WebDriverWait` and `lambda` to wait for the simple custom conditions:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

parent = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("some element")

wait.until(lambda ignore:
           parent.find_element_by_css_selector("child element").is_displayed()
           and parent.find_element_by_css_selector("child element").is_enabled()
           , "Element is clickable")
```

Use your own class:

```
class element_to_be_clickable(object):
    def __init__(self, element):
        self.element = element

    def __call__(self, ignored):
        if self.element.is_displayed() and self.element.is_enabled():
            return self.element
        else:
            return False

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

parent = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("some element")
wait.until(element_to_be_clickable(parent.find_element_by_css_selector("input")), "Element is clickable")
```

Comment: I thought that the selenium framework maintains all the functionality of its methods through all the languages it supports, but it seems not,  so my only option is to define my own waiting condition. Anyway thank you for answering.

Comment: Even though I did that, I still get the same error.